# (Summernote) - jQuery and Prototype framework compatibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs, summernote

I'm trying to integrate an WYSIWYG Editor on an existing project that uses Prototype framework. It's mandatory that the project keep using prototype and that the WYSIWYG editor has his own image uploader in JavaScript (upload from file). I can't use a PHP uploader.

So, I've tried to integrate Summernote in my project, as it uses jQuery, I'm having conflicts with Prototype. To make it work, I'm using:

`jQuery.noConflict();
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#summernote').summernote();
 });`.

The editor loads fine and works, but when I put the mouse over and out the icons they disappear.

I think the problem is not in the initialisation but in the summernote.js code itself. I've tried to apply the noConflict functionality to that code, but still not working.

Someone can help to fix this issue? Or can suggest another good open source editor?

P.S1: The instalation have been made as it should: http://summernote.org/getting-started/

P.S2: I've already tried several noConflict variations as stated on the link below. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: Take a look at one of my other answers http://stackoverflow.com/a/33290106/341491 - there is an event (probably `hide`) that Summernote is firing on those elements that makes the `Element#hide()` method fire. You would need to adjust the source code to change the event names.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I've thought about it too, so I've tried to delete and test one by one every `hide` call in the summernote.js file, unfortunately I'm not getting any hint. Now I'm testing each mouse event.

Answer (score 0):

It comes from the bootstrap tooltip, which conflicts with prototype.

Add this event after the tooltip is triggered:
Source: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/6921#issuecomment-45125243

```
jQuery(".YOURELEMENTS").on("hidden.bs.tooltip", function() { 
    jQuery(this).css("display", "");
});
```

and this css rule to avoid the flickering:

```
.YOURELEMENTS{
    display: inline-block !important;
}
```

Adapt the elements name to your needs.
For the css rule, "inline-block" also might be changed to "block"

Comment: Summernote without Bootstrap (Summernote Lite) still has conflict when using `jQuery.noConflict()`. https://jsfiddle.net/0pz1bmt5/