# Foundation, jQuery and Prototype.JS: Dropdown & DropdownMenu not working as intended

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation, prototypejs

I'm trying to use jQuery (2.x.x) and prototype.js (1.7.2), combined with foundation-sites 6 (tried 6.1.2, 6.2.0-rc.1). What has work with foundation 5 ever since leads to strange results now. The first interaction with the dropdown is working as expected, but further interactions increase the offset of the dropdown pane infinitely.

Additionally to jQuery and prototype.js I have these foundation components imported:

- foundation.core.js
- foundation.util.keyboard.js
- foundation.util.triggers.js
- foundation.util.mediaQuery.js
- foundation.util.box.js
- foundation.dropdown.js

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/4pqzmr7k/1/

Here is the callstack which shows the road to the inwards of prototype.js

```
$ (prototype.js:2048)
show (prototype.js:2168)
_methodized (prototype.js:456)
jQuery.extend.trigger (jquery.js:7825) ==> elem[type]();
(anonymous function) (jquery.js:7875)
jQuery.extend.each (jquery.js:360)
jQuery.fn.jQuery.each (jquery.js:137)
jQuery.fn.extend.trigger (jquery.js:7874)
Dropdown.open (foundation.dropdown.js:333)
(anonymous function) (foundation.dropdown.js:217)
```

I'm not completely sure if that is a bug in foundation or if I'm just doing it wrong. But with Foundation < 6 all worked fine. If I remove prototype.js all works fine, but I'am not able to do that because it's a dependency in our project.

Comment: Based on your call stack it looks like there is something in Foundation that is triggering a 'show' event on an element. Take a look at one of my other answers http://stackoverflow.com/a/33290106/341491 with more details. Basically adjusting the event from "show" to "foundation:show" or similar will solve the problem.

Comment: The event which is triggered is named show.zf.dropdown. jQuery splits the event name (namespace + event name) and calls elem[show]() on the DOM element - and in elem[show] a prototype callback is registered. Renaming it solves the problem, but it feels nasty.

Answer (score 1):

Add js:

```
<script>
/* jQuery no conflict */
jQuery.noConflict();

/* Workaround Foundation / Prototype conflicts */
if (Prototype.BrowserFeatures.ElementExtensions) {
    var disablePlugins = ['dropdown', 'tooltip', 'drilldown', 'dropdownmenu'];
    var preventPrototypeJS = function (method, disablePlugins) {
        var handler = function (event) {
            event.target[method] = undefined;
            setTimeout(function () {
                delete event.target[method];
            }, 0);
            console.log(method + ' - ' + disablePlugins);
        };
        disablePlugins.each(function (plugin) {
            jQuery(window).on(method + '.zf.' + plugin, handler);
        });
    };
    preventPrototypeJS('show', disablePlugins);
    preventPrototypeJS('hide', disablePlugins);
}
/* */
jQuery(function ($) {
    /* Foundation sites */
    $(document).foundation();
});
</script>
```